# Alignment when printing a series of records

Tags: shell-script, csv, printf, table

How can I resolve the problem of the tables going to the right. I just want it to be shown under `1`.

Here's my script with START added. The alignment has gone wonky now:

```
while IFS="," read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 f12
do
 printf "START %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %5s" $f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 $f5 $f6 $f7 $f8 $f9 $f10 $f11 $f12; # ifet the student id
done < records.csv
echo " Press <enter> to return to main menu"
read null
```

[image]

Comment: What is inside `records.csv`. Can you post at least sample contents?

Comment: Possibly the first column, as detected by the script is empty. Please check the output when you change `printf "%10s %10s %10s %5s %10s %5s %5s %5s %5s %10s %10s %10s" $f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 $f5 $f6 $f7 $f8 $f9 $f10 $f11 $f12;` to `printf "START %10s %10s %10s %5s %10s %5s %5s %5s %5s %10s %10s %10s" $f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 $f5 $f6 $f7 $f8 $f9 $f10 $f11 $f12;` and see where the START appears.

Comment: @Ned64 please look at up updated script above. i've put start in it. but still seems to go wonky

Comment: What editor are you using to edit  `records.csv` ? Run `cat -vet records.csv` are you seeing `^M$` at the end of any lines? As earlier requested, post a sample of your csv file as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a newline at the end of the printf statement, like so:

```
             printf "START %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %5s\n" $f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 $f5 $f6 $f7 $f8 $f9 $f10 $f11 $f12; # ifet the student id
```

(note the `\n`)

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because, you give only 5 positions for 4th field, but it may have six characters like `HARRY1` in your example:

```
printf "%10s %10s %10s %5s <...>
                       ^^^
```

However, there is nice prettifier in GNU/Linux [`column`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/column) which automatically selects column width depending on incoming data:

```
$ cat test.csv
Harry,2
Ed,3
Mary,4
Looooooooongname,8

$ sed 's/,/ /' test.csv | column -t
Harry             2
Ed                3
Mary              4
Looooooooongname  8

$ sed 's/,/ /' test.csv | grep -v Looooooooongname | column -t
Harry  2
Ed     3
Mary   4
```

May be it is better choice for you?

Comment: thanks. I might try that out if this method doesn't work out.